# Swagger is using API version out of date

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-node-express

I'm trying to use Swagger to document my API. Currently I threw together a quick express app using node. I'm using [swagger-node-express](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node-express) and trying to setup a basic GET following their example about the Pet store.

I getting the following error when I try my route. But in the network tab, I can see the GET being returned.

[image: Swagger UI screenshot]

Is there an updated version of Swagger which swagger-node-express can use?

Also I did see that [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) had "Build Failing" on its page.

So basically I'm not sure if the problem is with the swagger-node-express or the swagger version it is using.

Anyone have similar issues or know of a fix?

Comment: What happens if you put `http://localhost:8002/api-docs` in the URL instead?

Comment: @Ron I get a 404 if i try that URL. "Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:8002/api-docs".